# Why is ofstream as a class member can not be passed to thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, standard-library

I have write a class with operator () overload, I would like to pass this class like a function pointer to thread, so I place it in thread like the following. However, it failed to be compile, I noticed the ofstream is the reason it failed. Why is this wrong ?

```
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class dummy{

    public :
        dummy(){}
        void operator()(){}

    private:
        ofstream file;
};


int main()
{ 
  dummy dum;
  thread t1(dum);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Bet it has to do with trying to copy an iostream object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `std::basic_ofstream` copy constructor is deleted, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream). Consequently your `dummy` class copy constructor is also implicitly deleted. You need to move your object instead of copying it:

```
std::thread t1(std::move(dum));
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the instantiation of function template specialization `std::thread::thread<dummy &, void>` where you see that the `dummy` is passed as a reference and it tries to copy `dummy` object, including the `ofstream` (which can't be copied). You can get around that by using `std::ref` to actually copy the reference to `dum` into the thread instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>

class dummy {
    std::ofstream file;

public:
    dummy() {}
    void operator()() { std::cout << "in thread\n"; }
};

int main() {
    dummy dum;
    std::thread t1(std::ref(dum));
    t1.join(); // dont forget this
}
```

Comment: Note, if this isn't used in main() and dum goes out of scope you're in trouble. I'd prefer moving.

Comment: Sure, the `dummy` instance must outlive the thread so the `join()` must be done before the `dummy` goes out of scope. Which one that is preferable depends on the situation. The `dummy` could be populated with results by the thread that'd be available after the `join` etc.  and those situations I'd say that passing it by reference would be preferable.